# Is something special of while loop regarding the index?

Tags: python, python-2.7

Here is the code:

```
a = "218916754"
b = ""

while len(a) > 1:
    b = b + a[0]
    a = a[2:] + a[1]

b = b + a
print b
```

The result is `"281749561"`. My question is, how this happens? In this code, there is no `i`, no `i+=1` etc, how the iteration happens? Is something special about the while loop? I mean the index function is hidden in this while loop?

Comment: Have you tried stepping through the algorithm? If you can't do it in your head or on paper, consider http://www.pythontutor.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line:

> ```
> a = a[2:] + a[1]
> ```

results in a string that is one character shorter than the previous. Once this string has a length of 1, the loop exits.

Comment: Oh, I see: when you have action, you have a variable accordingly. Sounds like Zen.

Answer (score 0):

There is no "index function" or index "i" in a `while` clause.  Instead, code such as:

```
while <expression>:
    <body>
```

means, "repeat `<body>` as long as `<expression>` is True"

Answer (score 0):

Initially when we are programming we are always using indexes (commonly - i,x,y,t) to keep track of iterations of loops. It is because we always have a loop that we want to run for a know fixed number of iterations. But indexes are not something fundamental to the loop. Loops are tools which are much more than that.

A loop consists of a condition and body. The body is executed as many times, depending on whether the condition is `True` or `False`. (Conditions are boolean conditions).

So in the given code the condition is `len(a)>1`. That is - if the length of string "a" is greater than 1. So the body of the loop will be executed as many times as long as this condition is true. (You can also see, if wrongly implemented you could have loops that do not terminate).

To see what exactly is happening in this particular program, You can use the print statement inside the loop and a dummy variable "iteration_num" which I am using to keep track of the iterations. Go ahead and run the following code and see for yourself.

```
a = "218916754"
b = ""
iteration_num = 1
while len(a) > 1:
    b = b + a[0]
    a = a[2:] + a[1]
    print "iteration number: " + str(iteration_num)
    print "a: " + a
    print "b: " + b
    iteration_num = iteration_num + 1

b = b + a
print b
```